# git pull with ssh keys

Tags: git, github

I have generated ssh keys on windows. I did add my public to github. Then I added my SSH key to the ssh-agent. When I use git bash to connect remote server, my command is ssh user@host -p 2898. The server doesn't ask me for password only passhrase. The thing is, when I try to git pull, then git asks me to input password (not mine but global). I don't really know what to do. I tried to pass -i my private key, but did not help. Could anyone tell me what I do wrong, or give me an idea.

Comment: Are you pulling from the remote server or from your Windows? Did you put your SSH key on the remote server?

Comment: yeah i pull from remote one, and i i also put my ssh key to remote server

Comment: Did you configure SSH so that it uses your private key? Did you configure `git pull` so that it uses your SSH credentials?

Comment: hey, could you tell me  what do you mean saying to configure git pull? :)

Comment: In other words, in `.git/config` is there a git or https URL? In `~/.ssh/config`, is the access to the git server configured? And is it used by your local git?